# USB Directories not visible with Mac

Tags: macos

I recently had some virus on my USB. After cleaning (with PC antivirus), i got all my files back, but the directories on my USB are not shown when connected to my Mac (Lion) computer.
What can I do to access them with my Mac?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you still see them in the terminal ? (Your USB drive is mounted in `/Volumes/`)

Answer (score 2):

I think the MacOS does not show folders if they have the "x" flag missing.  Try going to a Terminal window, then changedir to the folder

```
cd /Volumes 
ls 
cd name-of-folder-with-stick
```

And there try

```
ls 
chmod 755 foldername
```

or even (for all files and folders there)

```
chmod 755 *
```